# Issue with bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert the data from this link to my SQL server
https://www.ian.com/affiliatecenter/include/V2/CityCoordinatesList.zip

I created the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblCityCoordinatesList](
    [RegionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RegionName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Coordinates] [nvarchar](4000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And I am running the following script to do the bulk insert

```
BULK INSERT tblCityCoordinatesList
FROM 'C:\data\CityCoordinatesList.txt' 
WITH 
( 
    FIRSTROW = 2, 
    MAXERRORS = 0, 
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

But the bulk insert fails with following error

```
Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

When I google, I found several articles which says the issue may be with RowTerminator, but I tried everything like \n\r, \n etc, but nothing is working.

Could anyone please help me to insert this data into my database?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try `ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'`.
it should work.

Comment: Awesome! that did the trick.  Can you please explain this '0x0a' thing? thanks.

Comment: '0x0a' is the hexidecimal value for ASCII character "new line" - I'm not sure what that worked and \n (also "new line") did not though...

Comment: For some reason I've never understood, when you put in '\n', MSSQL adds a '\r' to the front of it.

Comment: For this to work for me, I had to change all line endings in the CSV to be LF and not CRLF

Answer (score 23):

This can also happen if the number of columns mismatch between the table and the imported file

Comment: Yes, this can happen if you have a wrong FIELDTERMINATOR, as I had in my case :)

Comment: An example of this is when you are importing multiple CSVs in a script and you've checked that your format is good on the first file but suddenly a later file contains an extra column not reflected in your import-to table.   Be sure to check all your files for potential column number mismatches.

Answer (score 3):

I had this on SQL2019 when the FORMAT='CSV' option was used, and there was a comma on the end of each line in the source file. So the table your BULK inserting into needed to have an extra dummy field to cater for the fact each record has essentially a blank field in the source file.

![image: CSV file example]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't think this answer is unclear. It definitely helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message, and as you had mention, it was related to unexpected line ending.
In my case the line ending was specified in a fmt file as a Windows Line ending (CRLF), written as `\r\n`, and the data file to process has a Mac classic one (CR).

I solved it with an editor that can show the current line ending and change it. I used EditPad Lite wich shows the opened file line ending in the bottom bar and pressing it allow to replace with the expected one.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error, probably from the file encoding problem. I fixed it by opening the problem CSV file using Notepad++, select everything and copy to clipboard. Next, create a new text file (making sure it has the CSV file extension), open it using Notepad++, then paste the text to the new file. Save and close all files. You should be able to successfully load the new CSV file into the SQL server.

Answer (score -7):

you need run BULK INSERT - command from windows login (not from SQL). Now I don't have any examples

Comment: you should provide examples with your answers. Thanks.

Comment: BULK INSERT works just fine from within SQL Operations Studio