# Unable to read CSV file in MSSMS using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, oledb, bulkinsert

**RESOLVED: Opened in notepad and file did not save my deleted columns. Thanks for everyone's help!**

I'm trying to import a `.csv` file to read data. I'm trying to use a `BULK INSERT` statement by creating a staging table to temporarily hold that data. However, I'm getting an error after executing the following code:

```
-- Create a temporary table to hold the imported data
CREATE TABLE #StageTransactionsTable
(
    Date DATE,
    Description VARCHAR(255),
    Amount DECIMAL(10, 2)
);

-- Use BULK INSERT to import data from the CSV file
BULK INSERT #StageTransactionsTable
FROM 'C:\Users\eriks\Downloads\EXPORT (2).CSV'
WITH
(
    FORMAT = 'CSV',
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
);

-- Query the imported data
SELECT * FROM #StageTransactionsTable;

-- Drop the temporary table when you're done
DROP TABLE #StageTransactionsTable;
```

I keep getting this error:

> Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
> Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

I went into my `services.msc` and `downloads` folder to make sure the studio and server had permission to read and write. This is on my personal PC at home using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Everything is up to date, and I can complete any other usual task. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
Below is my .csv file in excel I'm trying to import. The middle column just contains the description of the location of the transaction. Just highlighted black for privacy.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8KnH.png

Below are the permissions that allow my studio to have my downloads tab in File Explorer.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AtVY.png

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937581/issue-with-bulk-insert

Comment: Please post some sample data.

Comment: This https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/issues/408 suggests that you replace `format = 'CSV'` with `DATAFILETYPE = 'char'`

Comment: Also are you certain this is a CSV file with thw correct columns? Open it in notepad and inspect and ensure it is what you expect.

Comment: SSMS (the studio?) isn't the thing needing access to the `C:\Users\eriks\Downloads` folder, that would be the SQL Server instance itself. Is the SQL Server instance actually running on your machine? If so, try moving the file to an accessible location like `C:\Temp`. If not, try moving the file to a File Share that's accessible to the SQL Server instance, or to a folder on its own file system.

Comment: Most probably due to mismatch of the number of columns in CSV vs temp table

Comment: I suspect the service account doesn't have access to your user direct, and it likely *shouldn't*. Put the file somewhere the service account can access.

Comment: You can use select * from openrowset bulk with single_clob command to see if you have access to actual file regardless of its format

Comment: It's good that you have a solution. Next time someone asks you to post sample data, post the raw data as it appears in the file. You've posted data as rendered by a spreadsheet app. If we're looking for a fault in the data, that won't show us.